# Is it worth specifying certain properties for IE, or just any other older versions? [Backwards Compatible]

Tags: css, browser, backwards-compatibility

I've been using `-webkit` and `-moz` for quite a few times now until this struck me. Aside from defining specific properties based on browsers and certain properties such as `break-inside` which are not widely supported,

Wouldn't

> border-radius: 5px;

makes it shorter for

> -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
>    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
>  
>   border-radius: 5px;

There are lots of other features which have been standardized but several examples still utilize the vendor prefixes and what are their purposes for doing so?

The former is supported by latest browsers but can we not assume almost everybody is using almost-latest browsers (especially NOT older versions of IE which certain rules apply)? (Even if people do not update their browsers, they are only left behind by just a few versions considering no one takes out a Nokia-old phone from a chest and started browsing)

Why should we use them? Why should we specify older IE specific rules or just older browser rules?

How much diving into older version would be enough? IE8?

Comment: The `-vendor-prefixes` are only relevant while a feature isn’t standardized yet. Once it is standardized and all the relevant browsers support it, there’s little reason to keep using them. It’s up to you how far back you want to go with compatibility, but `border-radius` in particular has been well established for many years now. IE is always the problem child and might warrant separate consideration.

Comment: Welp, so it's just the usual "Up to you" feature thing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my thoughts - before going into detail I have to say that I am a freak when it comes to browser support.

Up until a couple of years back I was trying to support from IE8 and upwards. The reason behind this logic was that people where "trapped" with Windows XP and IE8 was the latest version supported by Windows XP. By trapped I mean that they were cases like government pcs that were too costly to upgrade.

After Windows 7 has matured enough and Windows XP usage dropped, I tried to support IE9 and upwards. This essentially meant that even after useful properties came out (like flexbox) it took me a long time to migrate - so I was building layouts with tables for best browser support, etc.

However, Javascript Frameworks started dropping support for older browsers (including IE9), then CSS frameworks started dropping support. If you consider it for a while, MS itself has dropped support quite some time back. Major mobile companies drop support for their 2-year devices, so why should we support older browsers? As stated in in other answers, it depends on the audience - imagine the CEO of your best client-company having a laptop with Windows XP or other outdated device - wouldn't matter if anyone else used modern browsers..

So, it came down to a point a couple of years back that you have to select between following the stream and being modern or supporting older devices. I am all up for consistency and uniformity of content, so supporting modern features for a few select browsers and dropping them for others would be a no go for me. Flexbox was one of those properties that pushed me to skip older browser support - it vastly helped me reduced markup - thus making maintenance easier. At the same time, even Bootstrap decided to drop support for older browsers, so, must upgrade to keep pace with the competition.

Needless to say, the problem isn't just IE, but was also Android which took up to v4.4 in order for the stock browser to support specific properties - vh, flexbox wrapping, etc

These said, let me give you a straight answer:

- Don't bother with support for IE9 - not even 10. IE10 could be upgraded to 11 on the same OS, so it should be upgraded anyway for security reasons. IE9 is not supported by JS frameworks (eg Ember), lacks CSS3 transitions and other useful properties, like flexbox. Without these your designs would have to take many steps back if you were aiming for design consistency.
- As a sidenote IE10 started supporting their own interpretation of flexbox (sorry about all this persistence with flexbox, but it's one of the most useful properties). This means, that in order to support it properly, you would have to write a lot of CSS. Imagine adding 30kb of minified CSS to support just one browser that is fairly uncommon. Is it worth it?
- Some webkit browsers (like Opera) might still require vendor-specific prefixes for browser versions released 4 years ago -eg for CSS3 transforms. Tbh more important things are broken on such browsers (Opera included) that I would worry about other stuff more. Personally I only use the `-webkit-` prefix in select cases (eg flexbox properties that have matured quite lately).
- There might be some cases where browser-specific prefixes might come handy even in modern browsers, eg styling a range input or a scrollbar where you have to mess with browser-specific properties to achieve consistency. In such cases specific CSS hacks with vendor prefixes might be required.

As a final note, I would avoid any bleeding-edge properties, eg grid; learn what it does and how it works, but don't use it just yet. You should give a look at https://caniuse.com/ in order to have an idea about CSS properties and browser support.

However, it is up to you to decide and you should make your selection based on the requirements of your project. Two years back I would tell you to support as old as you can... back then you would be able to achieve the same things with different effort, but this is not the case any more. From a point onwards... older browsers can't keep pace.

Comment: You changed my mind on the IEs. I've never thought about even IE9 and 10 as obsolete, and if there's newer versions of IE on them, I know people start to use Edge in place of IE now. Even though I've considered Safari for webkit prefix, I haven't thought of Opera though (Are they widely used?). You just defined the "scope" the other answers are talking about and also included Android which I haven't even added to my considerations. 

tl;dr - So the answer for the question would No. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome my friend! It was a tough decision for me to make the jump to not supporting older browsers, but once I did I never looked back and had no regrets so far!

Answer (score 4):

Well... This is a really big topic so its hard to answer all of it but there are best practices that you should/could follow.

First - **Everything is based on YOUR SPECIFIC Audience.** Look at your analytics and see what browsers are being used. The data might surprise you especially if you have US Health care or government users. Tools like [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) will help you find unsupported rules in your CSS.

Next, It's best practice to **utilize feature detection** instead of targeting specific browsers. You can implement that by using [`@supports`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/#at-supports) in conditional code that works like a `media query`. This way your code is only being applied if the browser can use it. You can do similar detection in javascript using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Finally, I personally **recommend using a CSS post processor** or build script so you can stop worrying about prefixing (plus it will speed up your development with optional plugins). I tend to like a combo of [PostCSS](https://postcss.org/) and [Prefixfree](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree) (several Webpack customizations come with those included) but there are many similar options.

The main benefit is that the library tracks what needs prefixes and what doesn't so you write the non-prefixed version and the rest is taken care of.

---

There are no hard and fast rules but you should try to support your users' devices instead of pushing for upgrades. The nice thing about the above practices is that your *resulting code will be easier to maintain, future proof and targeted* to your users.

Comment: +1 for the useful libraries, but I'm aware PostCSS does this for us. However, I'd like to know something though: if the project you are working on is not for a client and just personal, what "range" would "target audience" scope?

Comment: @NeonNatureEX I think even a "personal" project would have some idea of where you expect it to be used. Is it something you want people to do on mobile? That's one set. Are you experimenting with the latest CSS? That's another set and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You **should not** worry about browsers older than IE 8. These browsers are barely used anymore and they do not support a lot of things. Please, refer to these to websites:

https://imagebox.com/industry/why-your-website-doesnt-look-the-same-in-every-browser/
http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/.

In terms of the various border-radius commands, make sure to use them all. I've found that if you don't include webkit and mozilla, you lose a lot of traffic. In my website, I usually include every variation of a command so I know for sure my website works. Better to have a large and ugly CSS code than a broken website.

Feel free to comment on this answer if you need more clarification.

Comment: That's why I started to wonder and ask the question. But I want to know why and how those vendor prefixes are actually related to traffic. Do they somewhat contribute to SEO or something?

Comment: They are related to traffic because if you don't support a wide variety of browsers, you lose potential users. If your website appears broken on some browsers, people will think it is unprofessional or unusable and leave.

Comment: Umm....that is exactly why I asked though. Vendor prefixes are being used even on standardized css properties. If the website is broken, that means the client must be using very very old browser (IE 6, etc) and I don't think there are too many people that use obsolete browsers. How come they would affect the traffic then if the percentage of people using old browsers is too low? Is it too high or something?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my answer. I was trying to say that if you want a bigger user base, your website needs to be usable in most browsers. Not all browsers need to look perfect. I wouldn't worry about older browsers so much, as long as it works most of the time. The earliest browser you should support is IE7 because most people are migrating to Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Microsoft Edge.